where to specify progamId on client side to interact with a progam if at all

I am trying to interact with a basic counter program using coral-xyz, deployed it in localnet and devnet
but failed to interact with both.
following soldev/course
Error: Simulation failed.
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist.
Logs:
[].
Catch the SendTransactionError and call getLogs() on it for full details.


I am going to assume that you are using Anchor.
The attempt to load a program that does not exists indicates that perhaps you didn't deploy the program in the cluster your are trying to access it from.
If deploying your program from devnet make sure you've updated your Anchor.toml to reflect this change
[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"

Also make sure you have enough devnet SOL to deploy the program.
You can airdrop yourself some using solana airdrop 5 when your local solana config is set to devnet.
Do not also forget to use an updated IDL of the deployed program on the client side with. anchor build will usually updated your IDL
